# How to toggle visibility of a view in Eclipse with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

One can set keyboard shortcut to show any given view. However, I don't see a way to set keyboard shortcut to hide any given view (or at least the active one) or even better to toggle visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a command "Close Part" to close the active workbench part.

Comment: This works better than *Minimize Active View or Editor* in my case as after closing a view and showing it again it's being shown almost exactly the same way as at the beginning. The only difference is tab order in case a view is stacked with other views.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command for "Minimize Active View or Editor" that you can assign a keyboard shortcut to, but there doesn't seem to be a similar command for Restore. I suppose that's because a minimized view can't have focus or be "active" and so there's no context in which a Restore command could be utilized.

Comment: The problem with *Minimize Active View or Editor* is that after minimizing a view all subsequent show actions show the view as if it was *Fast View*.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to minimize any view within eclipse.

to focus any view Alt + Shift + (and respective key)

EX : Alt + Shift + C, Shift + Tab ( Repeat Tab untio focus to minimize button.) , Enter